# Where can I find the theory of lift?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, aerodynamics, lift

Website, paper, book, anything that contains the whole theory.

Comment: What's your background and your proficiency in Math?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @basics Hi basics, thanks for asking, I have a degree in computer engineering, and my career has been mostly in software, coding, database admin, data architect. Throw any math at me.

Comment: @Community I only need a link to literature which describes the theory of lift. I am not asking for any detail in that theory. Detailed questions will come after I read the theory. Also, StackExchane specifically states that the questions here have to be mainstream. So, i need the mainstream theory of lift. Otherwise, if I ask a question and it it turns out that is not mainstream, then my question gets closed as it happened recently

Comment: [See how it flies](http://www.av8n.com/how/#contents)

Comment: @Farcher thanks for the tip. I have explored av8n.com and I couldn't find one critical piece of information: What is the main reason of the Angle of Attack of an airplane? Any idea why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

I leave you here a list of topics you can put together to build a detailed theory of lift.

**Preliminaries:**

- **non-viscous flows**: Euler equations (as the inviscid limit of Navier-Stokes, the most general mathematical model for the description of the dynamics of fluids); in the inviscid limit, you need to understand:

  - Helmoltz's and Kelvin's theorems about the dynamics of vorticity
- **non-viscous irrotational flows**: add the irrotational assumption, i.e. $\mathbf{\omega} = \nabla \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$, usually a good approximation in many flows in engineering applications. If these assumptions hold, then we can get

  - Bernoulli's theorem(s)

**Theory of lift, relying on Kutta-Jukowski theorem:**

- Kutta-Jukowski theorem and **Kutta condition** for 2D flows, around airfoils
- Kutta-Jukowksi theorem for 3D flows around wings and general 3D bodies

**References**

- Prandtl and Tietjens, *Applied Hydro- and Aeromechanics*. Contents of lectures of Prandtl gathered by one of his students. It's a very nice and enjoyable reading. Would you trust Prandtl?
- any other reference that puts together all the preliminaries and Kutta-Jukowski theorem I listed above
- Material in .pdf from an old version of the Aerodynamics course at the Politecnico di Milano:
  https://home.aero.polimi.it/quadrio/it/Didattica/dispensenuove.html.
  Unfortunately its only in Italian, but with automatic translators you could do it. I'd suggest this reading even if there is this little issue with the language, since I think it's the best material about these topics of Aerodyamics, especially

  - chapter 7: 2D airfoil
  - chapter 8: 3D wings and bodies, with a proof of the Kutta-Jukowski theorem

  Preliminaries are in:

  - chapter 1: Navier-Stokes and Euler equations
  - chapter 3: dynamics of vorticity
  - chapter 4: irrotational flows

Comment: These explain everything except lift. Thank you for the answer. I am serious about this. I have a more detailed question: What is the main role of the Angle of Attack of an airplane?

Comment: "I leave you here a list of topics you can put together to build a detailed theory of lift."   Well, if there was a "detailed theory of lift" then the topics would have been "put together" long ago.  But it looks like there isn't any !

Comment: I could have said "Kutta-Jukowski theorem", and let you find all the preliminaries you needed. In these few hours you couldn't even read about all you need for a theory of lift. Unfortunately, you're looking for "your answer". -1

Comment: I have already read these, In the past, not in those few hours of course. My question was downvoted with a stupid explanation

Comment: You have 3 questions on the very same topic, you've always argued with answers you got and you got 4 downvotes. Maybe this means something